# "make docs" fails while building doxygen v1.8.15 for rhel distros for s390x

Tags: doxygen

"make docs" fails while building doxygen v1.8.15 for rhel and sles distros for s390x.

Installed latex for rhel using package "doxygen-latex" v1.8.5

```
bash-4.2$ make docs VERBOSE=1
[ 82%] Generating Latex and HTML documentation.
cd /home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build/doc && /usr/bin/cmake -E env VERSION=1.8.15 /home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build/bin/doxygen
CMake Error: cmake version 2.8.12.2
Usage: /usr/bin/cmake -E [command] [arguments ...]
Available commands:
  chdir dir cmd [args]...   - run command in a given directory
  compare_files file1 file2 - check if file1 is same as file2
  copy file destination     - copy file to destination (either file or directory)
  copy_directory source destination   - copy directory 'source' content to directory 'destination'
  copy_if_different in-file out-file  - copy file if input has changed
  echo [string]...          - displays arguments as text
  echo_append [string]...   - displays arguments as text but no new line
  environment               - display the current environment
  make_directory dir        - create a directory
  md5sum file1 [...]        - compute md5sum of files
  remove [-f] file1 file2 ... - remove the file(s), use -f to force it
  remove_directory dir      - remove a directory and its contents
  rename oldname newname    - rename a file or directory (on one volume)
  tar [cxt][vfz][cvfj] file.tar [file/dir1 file/dir2 ...]
                            - create or extract a tar or zip archive
  time command [args] ...   - run command and return elapsed time
  touch file                - touch a file.
  touch_nocreate file       - touch a file but do not create it.
Available on UNIX only:
  create_symlink old new    - create a symbolic link new -> old

make[3]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/run_doxygen] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build'
make[2]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/run_doxygen.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build'
make[1]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/docs.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build'
make: *** [docs] Error 2
bash-4.2$
```

Any pointers on above errors will be helpful.

Comment: The error message is a bit general, could you get some more information about the error message  e.g. by running `make docs VERBOSE=1`

Comment: Updated description with the output of "make docs VERBOSE=1"

Comment: The command executed and failing is `/usr/bin/cmake -E env VERSION=1.8.15 /home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build/bin/doxygen`. What happens when you run that in isolation (in `/home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build/doc`)?

Comment: I don't know when the `env` part has been introduced with the `-E`, maybe you can check `man cmake` and look for the `COMMAND-LINE TOOL MODE` part and see if the `env` is mentioned there with the `-E`.

Comment: @DevSolar when run in isolation (in `/home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build/doc`) it throws same error

Answer (score 1):

From the old documentation of CMake: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html

I see

> -E: CMake command mode.
>
> For true platform independence, CMake provides a list of commands that
>   can be used on all systems. Run with -E help for the usage
>   information. Commands available are: chdir, compare_files, copy,
>   copy_directory, copy_if_different, echo, echo_append, environment,
>   make_directory, md5sum, remove, remove_directory, rename, tar, time,
>   touch, touch_nocreate. In addition, some platform specific commands
>   are available. On Windows: comspec, delete_regv, write_regv. On UNIX:
>   create_symlink.

So the used version of CMake is to old. Looks like, for the `-E env`, at least 3.1 is needed.

EDIT:

Regarding the minimal to use version:I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 6771, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6771).

EDIT 2:
Code of the pul request has been integrated in master on github.

Comment: Using cmake version 3.3.0:

```
[ 81%] Generating Latex and HTML documentation.
cd /home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build/doc && /usr/bin/cmake -E env VERSION=1.8.15 /home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build/bin/doxygen
entering extended mode
error: Problems running latex. Check your installation or look for typos in _formulas.tex and check _formulas.log!
dvips: DVI file can't be opened: _formulas.dvi: No such file or directory
error: Problems running dvips. Check your installation!
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/test/workspace/Doxygen_rhel/doxygen/build'
```

Comment: ```bash-4.2$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.3.0

bash-4.2$```

Comment: Which latex version have you installed?

Comment: bash-4.2$ latex -version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.13; using libpng 1.5.13
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with poppler version 0.26.5
bash-4.2$

Comment: My first guess is that this version of LaTeX is also a bit to old. Please try to upgrade to a bit newer version (not yet to the 2019 version as there are some problems with that version that are addressed but not yet in the LaTeX version).